# Unable to access an EJB deployed in jboss as 7

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jndi, ejb-3.0

I have deployed an EJB in Jboss As 7.0.

Following is what the deployment logs says about the JNDI binding of EJB.

> 19:21:43,269 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named
>   ManageEmployeeBean in deployment unit deployment "EJBTest1.jar" are as
>   follows:
>
> java:global/EJBTest1/ManageEmployeeBean!com.test.ejb.businessimpl.ManageEmployeeBeanRemote
>     java:app/EJBTest1/ManageEmployeeBean!com.test.ejb.businessimpl.ManageEmployeeBeanRemote
>     java:module/ManageEmployeeBean!com.test.ejb.businessimpl.ManageEmployeeBeanRemote
>     java:jboss/exported/EJBTest1/ManageEmployeeBean!com.test.ejb.businessimpl.ManageEmployeeBeanRemote
>     java:global/EJBTest1/ManageEmployeeBean
>     java:app/EJBTest1/ManageEmployeeBean    java:module/ManageEmployeeBean

This is how my client class looks like.

```
package com.test.ejb.test;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.test.ejb.bean.Employee;
import com.test.ejb.businessimpl.ManageEmployeeBean;
import com.test.ejb.businessimpl.ManageEmployeeBeanRemote;

public class Client {

    private static InitialContext initialContext;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            getInitialContext();
            System.out.println("CTX:"+initialContext);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Looking up EJB !!");
            ManageEmployeeBeanRemote remote = 
                    (ManageEmployeeBeanRemote)initialContext.lookup("/EJBTest1/ManageEmployeeBean!com.test.ejb.businessimpl.ManageEmployeeBeanRemote");
            System.out.println("setting employee..............");
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setFirstName("Renjith");
            employee.setLastName("Ravi");

            System.out.println("Adding employee");
            remote.addEmployee(employee);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        if (initialContext == null) {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
            prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "renjith");
            prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "user");
            initialContext = new InitialContext(prop);
        }
        return initialContext;
    }


}
```

Client is not able to find the service when I run it.

```
CTX:javax.naming.InitialContext@40964823
Looking up EJB !!
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: remote://localhost:4447 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server remote:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server remote:1099 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: remote: Name or service not known]]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1416)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:596)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:589)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.test.ejb.test.Client.main(Client.java:29)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server remote:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server remote:1099 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: remote: Name or service not known]]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:269)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1387)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server remote:1099 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: remote: Name or service not known]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:243)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: remote: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:76)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:239)
    ... 5 more
```

Can anyone tell me what am i missing here? 
I saw lots of threads on similar topic in stackoverflow, but none of them helped me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use the EJB Remote client from JBoss AS 5 (or earlier).

You need to use the JBoss AS 7 EJB Remote client and configure it as per the documentation at [AS7 JNDI Reference](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference) under the `Remote JNDI` heading.